# Place items right after the animation and inserbefore function mess

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5937o2x/)

I have an animation, that have to rearrange items in the list, the one we clicked on slides on the left and becomes active, the active element slides on the right and active class is remove from it.
However, i have some problems with the insertBefore function. Even if animation went right, it messes everything up. I am trying to figure out how to make everything look in place
Here is my script, but you can use fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log("it started");
   swapsies();



});
function swapsies()
{
    $('.lang').on('click', function() {
       // console.log("here");
        //.when(
        var $dist = 27;
        var $diststr="+="+$dist;
        var $diststr2="-="+$dist*2
        var $clicked=$(this);

        var $mcb= $clicked.css('margin-left');
        var $mnb=$clicked.css('margin-left');

        var $mab=$('.active').css('margin-left');

        $.when(
            $(this).animate({ "margin-left": $diststr2 }, 500),
            $(this).next().animate({ "margin-left": $diststr }, 500),
            $('.active').animate({ "margin-left": $diststr }, 500)
        ).done(function(){
                $clicked.insertBefore('.active');
                $(this).css('margin-left', "-54")
                $(this).next().css('margin-left', "27");
                $('.active').css('margin-left', "27");
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $clicked.addClass('active');
            });



    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure how exactly its supposed to re-arrange the items. but one way is this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7o6uuf0f/

minor change to the code in your done function

```
$clicked.insertBefore('.active');
$("#swapthis li").css("margin-left", "0");
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$clicked.addClass('active');
```

However you could also consider not reinventing the wheel, and use this.
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: wow that is a huge improvement, the only minor thing i would like to change is animation when it swaps with the last element, but it is for another guestion, i just add conditions. thank you a lot:)